# Issues with scenes with transparent background in vse

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, export, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm editing videos in blender and have been combining scenes made in the 3d view. After adding the scene to the vse I apply the blend I need, in this case overdrop. The preview shows exactly what I expect and I didn't have any issues before until now.

I've tried reinstalling the program and using an older version of blender, but nothing changed. Using the older version (2.75) did show the scenes background in the preview though. How do I get the effect I want in the final product?

In the link the image on the left is what the preview in blender is showing me, and the right is what the exporting video gives me. The speech bubble is an imported svg file and the text is made in blender.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VExk2.jpg

Comment: Use Alpha Over instead. And set your Render Background to transparent instead of sky.